# Spark lateral view in the dataset api

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at a simple sql query using several lateral view and unpacking jsons and trying to rewrite it using dataset api. I'm finding it problematic to reproduce the logical plan, since json_tuple can only be used once in a select, while lateral view does not seem to do it. Is there a way to reproduce the same behaviour as lateral view? Also, can someone comment on the performance of introducing additional projections and if the spark can optimize this?

Physical plan using sql:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [(cast(a0#117 as int) + cast(b0#118 as int)) AS x#101, (cast(a1#119 as int) + cast(b1#120 as int)) AS y#102]
+- Generate json_tuple(json2#7, k1, k2), [a0#117, b0#118], false, [a1#119, b1#120]
   +- Generate json_tuple(json#6, k1, k2), [json2#7], false, [a0#117, b0#118]
         ...
```

Physical plan using dataset api:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [a1#59, b1#60, (cast(a1#59 as double) + cast(b1#60 as double)) AS (a1 AS `integer` + b1 AS `integer`)#22, a0#13, b0#14, (a0 AS `integer` + b0 AS `integer`)#12, json#6, json2#7]
+- Generate json_tuple(json2#7, k1, k2), [a0#13, b0#14, (a0 AS `integer` + b0 AS `integer`)#12, json#6, json2#7], false, [a1#59, b1#60]
   +- *(2) Project [a0#13, b0#14, (cast(a0#13 as double) + cast(b0#14 as double)) AS (a0 AS `integer` + b0 AS `integer`)#12, json#6, json2#7]
      +- Generate json_tuple(json#6, k1, k2), [json#6, json2#7], false, [a0#13, b0#14]
```

Full example code for reference:

```
  val d0 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq(
      ("""{"k1": 1, "k2": "101"}""","""{"k1": 1, "k2": "101"}"""),
      ("""{"k1": 12, "k2": "201"}""","""{"k1": 12, "k2": "201"}"""),
      ("""{"k1": 13, "k2": "301"}""","""{"k1": 13, "k2": "301"}""")
    )
  ).toDF("json", "json2")

  // dataset api
  val d1 = d0
    .select(
      json_tuple($"json", "k1", "k2").as(Seq("a0", "b0")), $"a0".as("integer") + $"b0".as("integer"), col("*")
    )
    .select(
      json_tuple($"json2", "k1", "k2").as(Seq("a1", "b1")), $"a1".as("integer") + $"b1".as("integer"), col("*")
    )
  d1.explain()


  // sql part
  d0.createOrReplaceTempView("d0")
  val d2 = spark.sql(
  """
    select
      cast(a0 as int) + cast(b0 as int) as x,
      cast(a1 as int) + cast(b1 as int) as y
    from d0
    lateral view json_tuple(json, 'k1', 'k2') A_json as a0, b0
    lateral view json_tuple(json2, 'k1', 'k2') B_json as a1, b1
    """
  )
  d2.explain()
```